# Inconsistent aspect ratio

Tags: bug, user-profile-page

My image appears with different aspect ratios in different locations, making it difficult to wear a hat properly.  I tried replacing my old GIF image with a PNG version, but it still changes.  The problem isn't getting to work at all, but getting it to look the same everywhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include some images of where these different renderings affect the hat placement? Also, since this is probably a network-wide issue, it may need to be raised on [Meta.SE](//meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: can you give url to the "different locations" it seems odd the aspect ratio should change (they should always be square, I thought)

Comment: There is the page where you add the hat (first picture) which shows the original aspect ratio.  There is my page (second picture).  There are also all the little icons, but they look even worse.